# The correct way to develop an application using Kofax VRS support

Tags: c#, kofax, document-imaging

I'm so confused when dealing with Kofax sometimes...  Back in the day (years and years ago) I would develop an application for the purpose of scanning, viewing, and printing documents using the Kofax ImageControls Toolkit.

The last time I developed an application with the toolkit was awhile ago but it was in c#.  I remember even back then I could not find anything updated on the toolkit and ended up having to use the latest one I could get my hands on `Kofax ImageControls Toolkit v3` and that would allow my to utilize Kofax's VRS v4 software.

Fast forward many years later and I'm at it again trying to create another application that will utilize the latest VRS software by Kofax (v5).  The problem is I'm now in a Windows 10 environment using c# with Net framework 4.5.2.  I'm trying to understand what Kofax recommends people using to develop applications to utilize the VRS 5 software.  Are we still supposed to be using a toolkit (v3.1) that was developed back in 1998???  I have seen traces of v3.75 that seems to have come out around 2003 but I can't get my hands on that.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to how I can develop an application that uses the VRS software for image processing?

Comment: Sounds like a job for _Technical Support_

Comment: I was kinda hoping that someone from kofax might be monitoring the 'kofax' tags.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's still the same old toolkit. However, there's Atalasoft (now also a Kofax/Lexmark company) DotImage that has managed .NET classes. They do not have the features of VRS, but that's the current imaging SDK preferred by Kofax. Might be worth a look.

Comment: Atalasoft is good(cost aside), I've used them several times in the past.  The VRS was just a gimmick anyhow.  It's just a raw image in memory with filters.  Personally, I would not waste my time with Kofax,

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at "C:\Program Files x86\Kofax\Imgctls\bin\Toolkit.dll"

Kofax uses this .NET dll do the magic in their VRSTestConsole.exe.
But, I was not able to find any documentation on this dll.